# Scala operator oddity

Tags: scala

When I invoke + on 2 I get an Int back, but when its done using explicit method call I get Double instead.

```
scala> 2+2
res1: Int = 4

scala> 2.+(2)
res2: Double = 4.0
```

It seems that .+() is invoked on implicit converted Int to Double.

```
scala> 2.+
<console>:16: error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method + in class Double of type (x: Char)Double
and  method + in class Double of type (x: Short)Double
match expected type ?
              2.+
                ^
```

Why is that so ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The reason is not in explicit method call -- by writing `2.+` you specifying Double on the left side and then calling addition operator on it:

```
scala> 2.
res0: Double = 2.0
```

Comment: That is strange, glad they depracate it.

Answer (score 20):

In Scala 2.9 and before, `2.` is interpreted as `2.0` so the ambiguous dot denotes a float literal. You’d explicitly call the method by using the syntax `(2).+(2)`.

The ambiguous floating point syntax will however be deprecated in 2.10:

```
scala> 2.+(2)
<console>:1: warning: This lexical syntax is deprecated.  From scala 2.11, a dot will only be considered part of a number if it is immediately followed by a digit.
       2.+(2)
       ^
<console>:2: warning: This lexical syntax is deprecated.  From scala 2.11, a dot will only be considered part of a number if it is immediately followed by a digit.
              2.+(2)
              ^
<console>:8: warning: This lexical syntax is deprecated.  From scala 2.11, a dot will only be considered part of a number if it is immediately followed by a digit.
              2.+(2)
              ^
res1: Double = 4.0
```

Comment: BTW, why there are three warnings?

Comment: Don’t know. But of course it is still a snapshot (and a self-compiled one).