# Shorthand arithmetic operators return different results in Scala - EG: 3 + 2 != 3.+(2)

Tags: scala, operators, arithmetic-expressions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Scala operator oddity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655080/scala-operator-oddity)

I'm very new to Scala and I read that in this language everything is an Object, cool. Also, if a method has only 1 argument, then we can omit the '.' and the parentesis '( )', that's ok.

So, if we take the following Scala example: `3 + 2`, '3' and '2' are two `Int` Objects and '+' is a method, sounds ok. Then `3 + 2` is just the shorthand for `3.+(2)`, this looks very weird but I still get it.

Now let's compare the following blocks on code on the `REPL`:

```
scala> 3 + 2
res0: Int = 5

scala> 3.+(2)
res1: Double = 5.0
```

What's going on here? Why does the explicit syntax return a `Double` while the shorthand returns an `Int`??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`3.` is a `Double`.  The lexer gets there first.  Try `(3).+(2)`.

Comment: yup, but note that if you type `3.+(2)` in to Scala 2.10 you get `warning: This lexical syntax is deprecated.  From scala 2.11, a dot will only be considered part of a number if it is immediately followed by a digit.`