# Why is the .+() method deprecated in scala?

Tags: scala

Just wondering why I'm seeing the following in my REPL:

scala> 5.+(9)
warning: there were 1 deprecation warning(s); re-run with -deprecation for details
res18: Double = 14.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you follow the instructions and run the REPL using `scala -deprecation`, you'll see the reason for the deprecation:

```
scala> 1 + 1
res0: Int = 2

scala> 1.+(1)
<console>:1: warning: This lexical syntax is deprecated.  From scala 2.11,
a dot will only be considered part of a number if it is immediately followed
by a digit.
       1.+(1)
       ^
res1: Double = 2.0
```

Tested on Scala **2.10.1**

Comment: Oh! So when the addition is performed using the 1.+(1) syntax it's converting the type to a Double as well as performing the addition, when really it should be consistent with the result of the 1 + 1 syntax and keeping the type as an Int?

Comment: There was an issue with overloading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655080/scala-operator-oddity

Comment: Yeah, a space is required between an Int and `+`. Checked on **Scala 2.10.3** as well.